# Maximum number of linearly independent vectors subject to a constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry

Say there are $n$ vectors $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. What is the maximum number of such vectors I can have such that they are linearly independent and their first $k$ entries sum to zero?

Without the sum constraint, the answer is of course $d$. I can see the answer for some simple cases with $d=3$, $k=1,2$ etc., but I can't think of a way to approach this in general. Any hints?

Comment: In your experiments with $d=3$, did $k=1,2,3$ all give the same answer? Because they should.

Comment: Yes, $d=3$ and $k=1,2$ both give the answer $2$. Not sure what happens in higher dimensions.

Comment: Try lower dimensions: $n=2$ with $d=1,2$ (note that the sum must be $0$ in those cases).

Comment: For this to be meaningful, I need $d>1$  (otherwise with my constraint it's just zero) and $k<d$

Comment: No, $k=1$ and $k=d$ makes complete sense, it's just that the only allowed sum in those cases is $0$. If you have another sum in those cases, you get $d$ linearly independent vectors, which doesn't fit in with every other case. Also, why not try $d=4$?

Comment: Okay, for $k=1$ and any $d>1$, the answer is $d-1$, since the first coordinate is zero and I can get $d-1$ linearly independent vectors

Comment: So in general, for $k=1$, you got $d-1$. And for $d=3, k=2$ you got... $3-1$. Now, if you had to guess, what would you think the answer was?

Comment: Well, $d-k$ i think

Comment: Does that fit with your result for $d=3, k=2$?

Comment: I think it's $d-1$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set of vectors consisting of the vector with the first $k$ coordinates $1$ (and the remaining components $0$), the vectors with $1$ as first component and $-1$ as $i$th component for $2\leq i\leq k$ (otherwise $0$), and the vectors with only a $1$ as the $j$th component for $j>k$. This set is a basis for $\Bbb R^d$.

Say you have a vector where the sum of the first $k$ components is zero (in the standard basis). What property does that vector have in the basis described above? How many linearly independent such vectors can you have?